# Sibling selector in styled mui@v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Todo: Achieve a sibling selector in material-ui@v5 styled function.

```
.root + .root {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

To achieve the same with material-ui@v4 `makestyles` is simple. Have a look at below code:

```
    root: {
            width: '100%',
            '& + $root': {
                marginTop: spacing(1),
            },
        },
```

but I have no success with mui new api's for styled(). I have tried a few alternatives, something like this will generate such code.

```
const Root = styled(Box)(({ theme: { spacing } }) => ({
    [`& + .${Root}`]: {
        marginTop: spacing(1),
    },
}));

<style data-emotion="css" data-s="">.css-43e1lt+.NO_COMPONENT_SELECTOR{margin-top:8px;}</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining emotion's sibling selector with mui styled function, this is how we can make it work.

```
const Root = styled(Box)(({ theme: { spacing } }) => ({
    '& + &': {
        marginTop: spacing(1),
    },
}));
```